# AngularJS ui-route $state, $scope and controller event loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm kinda new with this UI-Route I know it's very powerful but i'm having problem working on it, I have use AngularJS before but not that often and this time i really want to use it so given that my questions goes like this (I've search everywhere regarding this but no luck for me):

The scenario is I have Index.html on that page I have two views 
which are "**News**" and "**Testi**" both are confined on a div

So knowing that I added App.js (which will contain the initial code for my AngularJS implementation):

```
var app = angular.module('wrcheese', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/Views/Index.html',
        views: {            
            'main': {
                templateUrl: '/Views/App/home.html'
            },
            'testi': {
                templateUrl: '/Views/App/testimonial.html'                
            }
        },
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })    
});
```

and my controller goes like this (homeController.js)

```
'use strict';
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.welcomeMessage = 'Welcome to WeRCheese';
});
```

my problem is that I'm trying to access that "welcomeMessage" on my home.html page but wasn't able to, what strange is that when i put in a breakpoint on my controller it wasn't hit it seems the controller does not exist.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong because I don't have any problem when i use ngRoute before.

Lastly, how do you add in a factory?

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $state, homeFactory) {
});
```

or

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'homeFactory', function ($scope, $state, homeFactory) { }]);
```

TIA.

I was having problem adding a comment my mistake for not realizing that I need to edit my question here. Anyway for my problem I was able to load the controller via different page but I'm still having problem loading the controller on the Index.html i tried updating the .state -> tried on different approach i.e. use '', '/', 'index' in the views.

```
.state('home', { 
    url: '', or '/', or 'index',
    templateUrl: '/Views/Index.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
```

But still the controller is not loading, to be specific I have tried adding this line on my Index.html {{ welcomeMessage }} just to verify that the controller was/has been loaded properly.

Comment: Post your html code

Answer (score 0):

When you have add `views` property to a `state`, the original `template`, `templateUrl` properties will be ignored, so you have to bind controllers in `views`.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'Views/Index.html',      <----- will be ignored
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: 'Views/App/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        },
        'testi': {
            templateUrl: 'Views/App/testimonial.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    },
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'        <----- will be ignored
})
```

For `factory`: after defined it, you can inject it by both the ways you posted.

refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6iJwg6ZMYt3RGrGBP1iX?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('wrcheese', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {            
            'main': {
                templateUrl: '/Views/App/home.html',
                controller : 'HomeCtrl'
         },
            'testi': {
                templateUrl: '/Views/App/testimonial.html',                
                controller : 'HomeCtrl'
            }
        },
    })    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: { 
            '@': {
                templateUrl: '/Views/Index.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm' 
            },      
            'main@home': {
                templateUrl: '/Views/App/home.html'
            },
            'testi@home': {
                templateUrl: '/Views/App/testimonial.html'                
            }
        }
    });
```

using `controllerAs` is a best practice